# How to compare a number string and it's reverse to find the next highest palindrome?

Tags: javascript, string, function, compare, palindrome

I am trying to build a function that takes a price with 2 decimal points and finds the next highest palindrome. I know there are several other ways to approach this, but I am curious why my method is not working. I am new to JS so this might be a simple one. Any advice would be great.

I broke it into smaller chunks with explanations of what I want it to do below:

```
var ask = prompt("Enter a price");

var reverseIt = function (x) {

    x = (parseFloat(x) * 100).toString();

    for (var i = (x.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        x.substr(i, 1);
    }
    return
};
```

The **reverseIt** function takes an argument removes the decimal (* 100) and reverses the number.

```
var removeDec = function (j) {

   return (parseFloat(j) * 100).toString();

}
```

The **removeDec** function takes an argument, removes the decimal point (* 100), and converts it back to a string. Is this redundant for comparing two "number" strings? Should I use the **Number()** and **String()** functions instead?

```
var findDrome = function (i) {

    for (var i; removeDec(i) != reverseIt(i); i += (1 / 100)) {

        if ((removeDec(i) + 1).toString() == reverseIt(i)) {

            document.write(i + (1 / 100));
        }
    } return
};

findDrome(ask);
```

The findDrome function takes the ask prompt at the start as an argument. If the number without a decimal doesn't match the reverse without a decimal, then increments it by 0.01. Right before the loop ends, I wanted it to check if the number prior +1 (since it is * 100) is equal to the reverse and if so write the next number.

It wasn't working, so I tried adding parseFloat and toString to specify stricter/more explicit conversions. I also used the loose equality operators, but it's still not working.

**My questions:** Is this a conversion or syntactical problem or can you not compare the output of 2 functions? Should I instead compare 2 variables and if so how do I assign the for loop in the **reverseIt** function to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a number of issues. First, your `reverseIt` function never returns a reversed value. The variable `x` is passed in but it's never updated in the `for` loop - `x.substr()` creates a new string instance but it's never assigned back to `x` so its value never changes. As it is, your `for` loop in `findDrome` goes infinite since `reverseIt` returns `undefined`.

Another - possible - problem is that you're incrementing a floating-point number by `1/100` but floating point values have no exact representation. I don't know if this is actually affecting your code (since it currently never returns a proper value) but it's something you may have to worry about. This would likely affect `parseFloat` (which may return a slighly different floating-point value than the string it parses).

Using [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) would truncate the number to 2 decimal digits. You could then turn the number to a string and remove the decimal dot character, rather than converting the number back and forth between string and number.

You may want to read up on [floating-point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/) (if you're not already familiar with it).

As a last comment, you should *never, ever* rely on Javascript terminating your statements - you should always use `;` to terminate a statement like in other proper C-style languages. Leaving out `;`-s (even if Javascript lets you get away with it) is considered very poor practice.

Comment: `var ask = prompt("Enter Price");

var a = ""

var reverseIt = function (x) {

    x = (parseFloat(x) * 100).toString();
 
    for (var i = (x.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
     
     a = (a + String(x.substr(i, 1)));
     
    } return a;
};

var b = parseFloat(reverseIt(ask));


var removeDec = function (j) {

   return (parseFloat(j) * 100).toString();

}

var c = parseFloat(removeDec(ask));


if (b == c) {
document.write("Palindrome");
}else {
document.write("Not a Paindrome!");
}` Thanks for your help! Figured out the top part, now I need to read up on floating point arithmetic & I got it!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to the help above! Here is how the fixed program works:

```
var ask = prompt("Enter a price to find the next palindromic price");

var removeDec = function (j) {
    return parseInt(j * 100);
};

var c = removeDec(ask);
```

This prompts a price and multiplies it by 100 to remove the decimal point and avoid floating point arithmetic. The **parseInt** removes any decimals smaller than the hundredths place.

```
var reverseIt = function (x) {
    var a = ""
    x = x.toString();
    for (var i = (x.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        a = (a + String(x.substr(i, 1)));
    }
    return Number(a);
};

var b = reverseIt(c);
```

The **reverseIt** function takes an argument, converts it to string and adds each character in reverse to an empty string (a=""). **Var a** is then returned as a number. The empty string is important for storing the reverse number and is a big reason why my code wasn't working before.

```
var e = Math.pow(10, (String(c).length - 1));
```

**Var e** was added to take into account varying place values to left side of the decimal. Later this helps check if a number is equal to its reverse by adding a 1 to both sides of the number. **Var e** counts the length of **var c** (entered value with decimal removed) and finds the appropriate power of 10 to add later. So if you entered **14.40** * 100 then later it will check if **1440** + 1 is equal to **0441** + 1000.. or **10^3**. This test is important later in order to exit the loop. This is where my code was failing before because I didn't take adding a number to the reverse into account and I was trying to add decimals which aren't as predictable.

```
if (c == b) {
    document.write("$" + (c / 100) + "... This price is already palindrome!")
} else {

    for (c; c !== b; c++) {
        b = reverseIt(c);
        if ((c + 1) == (b + e)) {
            document.write("The next palindromic price is $" + ((Number(c) + 1) / 100));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, If the original number and it's reverse are not equal then a loop begins that increments the value by 1 until the **entered number + 1**  is equal to the **reversed number + e**. So effectively the loop finds the number right before the loop ends, writes it and then breaks out of the loop. This palindrome finder seems to work smoothly with values big and small, no matter where you put the decimal point. Glad I got it working... it was a great learning experience figuring it out!